# Vertical viewpager doesn't work properly on Android 9

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I use this custom viewpager for having vertical scroll. It works perfectly on all Android versions except on Android 9. The swipe to go to bottom page doesn't work properly.

Have you got some investigation ways?

Thank you very much!

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        void onTouchDown();

        void onTouchUp();

        void onTouchMove();
    }

    private OnTouchListener mListener;

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener l) {
        super.setOnTouchListener(l);
    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y setNum to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mListener.onTouchDown();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mListener.onTouchUp();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mListener.onTouchMove();
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }
}
```